# Why it is opposite for negative integers when it comes to bigger or smaller number?

Tags: real-analysis

Example :Why (-5) is smaller than (-2). And can you explain the reason behind it.

Comment: $$  -5 + 3 = -2 $$

Comment: Jeez.... no need for downvotes.  It's a legitimate question and valid confusion and well expressed.

Comment: @fleablood Agreed. I think there is often a general disregard for lower level math questions among the mods, even good ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$-5°$ is *colder* than $-2°$, while $2°$ is *colder* than $5°$.

Comment: Very nice example of a real world application of the "number line" and good real world example were the linguistic  "$-5$ is *adjective*er than $-2$" makes intuitive and linguistic sense *in English* (and not just in "Math Talk").

Comment: @fleablood: warm thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

$a$ is less than $b$ just when $b-a$ is positive. Geometrically, that means $a$ is to the left of $b$ on the usual number line.

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse "smaller" and "larger" with "less than" and "greater than"! The words "smaller" and "larger" refer to magnitude, whereas "less than" and "greater than" refer to order. $-5$ is *larger* than $-2$ because it is further from $0$, that is,
$$|-5|>|-2|$$
However $-5$ is *less* than $-2$ because it is to the left of it, that is
$$-2-(-5)=3>0$$

Answer (score 0):

The terminology is not that $-5$ is "smaller than" $-2$, instead it is that $-5$ is *less than* $-2$, which we express in notation as $-5 < -2$. And the reason for this notation and terminology is that the $<$ relation obeys some important and useful mathematical properties, in particular the trichotomy law, and the transitive law, and other laws like $a<b \implies a+c < b+c$.

When using inequalities, the proper notation is $a<b$ or $a>b$, which you may properly read out loud as "$a$ is less than $b$" or "$a$ is greater than $b$". But should avoid the "larger" and "smaller" terminology, which does not have a standard meaning when discussing inequalities.

Nonetheless, sometimes one informally uses "larger" and "smaller" terminology in the sense of absolute values, where one thinks of the absolute value as a measurement of how large the number is: perhaps one might informally say that $-5$ is "larger than" $-2$ because $|-5|=5$ is *greater than* $|-2|=2$.

Answer (score 0):

The set ${\mathbb Z}$ of all integers is usually [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integers#Construction) as the [Grothendiek group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_group) constructed from the monoid $({\mathbb N},+)$ of natural numbers. In this construction, the ordering is defined by $[(a, b)]<[(c, d)]$ iff $a+d < b+c$. It is very easy to check that this definition implies $-5 < -2$ because $-5$ is the class $[(0, 5)]$ and $-2$ is the class $[(0, 2)]$.

Comment: Yeah, I really don't think the OP is ready for this type of explanation.

Comment: @fleablood It is not only an explanation. It is also a proof.

Comment: I don't think the OP is ready for this type of proof.

Answer (score 0):

What does "big" and "small" mean?

It could mean two different things and in mathematics we have two different methods of dealing with it.

One: Imagine we line all the numbers on a line.   At one point we have $0$ as our central focus point.  To the right we have $1$ and to the right of that we have $2$ and so on and advancing further and further to the right we have all the possitive numbers receding miles and miles in to the distance, the line going forever further and further to the right the numbers being larger and and larger receding to the distance.

To the left of $0$ we have all the numbers, coming from the far distant horizon on the far left approaching from the left and moving to the right to get approach us and our focus point.

Watch!  Here they come!  $-10, -9, -8$ thet are moving to the right to reach us.  $-3, -2, -1$ and finally $0$.  The have arrived.... and there they go.  They are continuing onto the right.  $1$,$2$,$3$, now the are going away from us (us being us standing at the $0$ focus point) ... $8$, $9$, $10$.

In this case the progress of going from left to right is what we mean by being "greater"  $a < b$ means $b$ is further to the right than $a$.

That's all.

$-5 < -2$ because in the march of numbers from left to right $-5$ came first.  And $2 < 5$ because in the march of numbers from left to right $2$ came first.

More formally:  The numbers are divided into to types. Positive and negative.  Mathematicians in the abstract dissection, and distaste of subjective (and therefore fallible) and emotional, often consider these distinctions arbitrary.  But emotionally and subjectively, the  positive numbers that are larger, greater, above, to the right of zero.  These are the numbers that are have direct physical existence. These are the numbers for measuring a positive bank balance, traveling past a point, measuring how long its been since a historical event. And negative numbers that are smaller, less than, below, to the left of zero.    These are the numbers that measure the absence of presence. These measure how far you are in debt, how far you must go to reach a point, a countdown to an event yet to come, how far under the surface you are.

But to the rigorous mathematician:  Some numbers, in particular "$1$" are "greater" than $0$ and others are "less" than $0$ and is arbitrary and abstract.

And to compare two numbers to each other,  if $a -b$ is positive and greater than $0$ we say that $b < a$ (or $a > b$).  For example, which is larger $a=5$ or $b=3$.  Well if we subtract $5-3 = 2$ that is greater than $0$ so $3 < 5$.  And if $a-b$ is negative and less than $0$ we say $a < b$ (or $b > a$).  For example, which is larger  $a=19$ or $b=27$.  Well if we subtract $19 -27 = -8$ that is less ant $0$ so $19 < 27$.

And this works for negative numbers.  Which is larger  $a = -5$ or $b=-3$.  Well if we subtract $-5 - (-3) = -5 +3 = -2$ that is less than $0$ so $-5 < -3$. And if $a=-19$ and $b=-27$ we get $-19 -(-27)=-19+27 = 8$ and that's positive so $-19> -27$.

But, honestly, I think simply thinking $-19$ is further to the right than $-27$ so $-27 > -19$ is the most straightforward way.  I was taught that with a "number line" in the first grade and it hasn't failed my in over 50 years.

....

Two:  Sometimes we talk about the *magnitude* of something.   If we stand at $0$ and we look to see how far away a number is.  $19$ is $19$ away but $27$ is bigger and  further away.  But look in the *other* direction.  $-3$ is $3$ away but $-5$ is further away.  Look at $32$ and $-64$.  $32$ is $32$ away in the positive direction but $-64$ is $64$ away in the negative direction.  Well $64$ is more than $32$ so shouldn't is some way we should say $-64$ is bigger than $32$?

Yes, and this is *ignore* whether numbers are positive or negative and just being concerned with their *magnitude*.

We can this distance away from $0$ the *absolute* value and $|-64| = 64$ and $|32| = 32$ and $|-64| > |32|$ so $-64$ is larger *in magnitude* than $32$ *if we disregard positivity/negativity*.

....

But mathematicians *need* to be consistant.

If One:  $b$ is further to the right of $a$ and $a$ is further to the right of $b$ we say $b$ is *greater than* $a$ and $a$ is *less than* $b$.  And this is what mathematicians mean when they say a number is greater than another.  In order to be perfectly clear, it's best to say "greater" and not "bigger" or "larger" (although "more" is okay).

If Two:  we want to talk about  how far something is from an origin of $0$ and *strip* away all reference to *direction*.  We talk of "absolute value" or "magnitude" or "normalizing a value".  We *might* **in**formally talk of $-64$ being "bigger" than $32$ but we shouldn't and we should always stress we are talking about it being bigger "*in magnitude*".